# How to combine these two methods (async and non-async) into one?

Tags: c#, methods, async-await, refactoring, synchronous

How can I combine these two methods and put as one...

```
class DataRulesPSScripts
{
    PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
    
    public IEnumerable<object> RunScriptBlock( ScriptBlock scriptBlock, Dictionary<string, object> scriptParameters )
    {
        var vars = scriptParameters.Select( p => new PSVariable( p.Key, p.Value ) ).ToList();
        return scriptBlock.InvokeWithContext( null, vars );
    }
    
    public async Task<ScriptBlock> CreateScriptBlock( string pSScript )
    {
        ps.AddScript( pSScript );
        var scriptBlock = (await ps.InvokeAsync())[0].BaseObject as ScriptBlock;
        return scriptBlock;
    }
}
```

these two methods are called in a different class in a different method like this. 'ds' is object for class  DataRulesPSScripts

```
private async Task<IEnumerable<object>> GenerateValuesFromScript( Dictionary<string, EntityProperty> arg, string pwScript )
{
    var pars = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    pars.Add( "_", arg );
    var scriptBlock = await ds.CreateScriptBlock( pwScript );
    var results = ds.RunScriptBlock( scriptBlock, pars ).ToList();
    return results;
}
```

Comment: trying to figure out how can i optimize this..and have one method instead of two

Comment: if I do that then I get error at line where I am calling it i.e. var results = ds.RunScriptBlock( pwScript, pars ).ToList(); and error is task<IEnumerable> does not contain a definition for .ToList()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write this:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<object>> CreateAndRunScriptBlock(
  string pSScript, 
  Dictionary<string, object> scriptParameters)
{
  ps.AddScript(pSScript);
  var scriptBlock = ( await ps.InvokeAsync() )[0].BaseObject as ScriptBlock;
  var vars = scriptParameters.Select(p => new PSVariable(p.Key, p.Value)).ToList();
  return scriptBlock.InvokeWithContext(null, vars);
}
```

Usage:

```
return ( await ds.CreateAndRunScriptBlock(pwScript, pars) ).ToList();
```

Alternative:

```
var items = await ds.CreateAndRunScriptBlock(pwScript, pars);
return items.ToList();
```

Also perhaps the method itself may directly return a list:

```
public async Task<List<object>> CreateAndRunScriptBlock(
{
  ...
  return scriptBlock.InvokeWithContext(null, vars).ToList();
}
```

*Remark*

`GenerateValuesFromScript` returns a `IEnumerable` thus the `ToList` is theorically useless (in this method).

Comment: shouldnt it be Task<IEnumerable>

Comment: public async Task<IEnumerable<object>> CreateAndRunScriptBlock

Comment: yes i did that as mentioned in comments , it gives error that Task<IEnumerable> does not contain a definition for .toList()

Comment: Maybe a trivial remark, but did you think of *using 
System.Collections.Generic* ?

Comment: @Olivier List<object> does not contain a definition for GetAwaiter